# Calculate the difference in total days between two dates

Tags: php

i would like to subtract two dates, and have it show me the number of days between the two dates ($current_hour give me a actual hour):

```
$a = date('Y-M-d' , 1705809951);
$b = date('Y-M-d', $current_hour);

$start_date = $a;
$end_date = $b;
 
$interval = date_diff(date_create($start_date), date_create($end_date));
echo "$interval->y years, $interval->m months, $interval->d days";
```

With this i get it to show me the years, months, and days, but how can I get it to calculate the total number of days?

Or...

$current_hour = 22-jan-2024
How can i transform it to an integer? That is, as $a that $a = 1705809951 and is equivalent to decem-2021

Comment: Use `$interval->days`

Comment: Didn't I mention that in your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77853657/understanding-date-diff-in-leap-years)?

Comment: @Barmar Thnx for ur answer again! ^^I want the total days that the subtraction equals. Setting interval->days shows me the difference between the days of the subtraction

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you're making. Can you update the question and show your desired result?

Comment: @Barmar Okay, I'm going to put it another way. I have $current_time. $current_time is a string. (output example -> 1970-Jan-01)
How can I transform that date to unix? Like the variable $a (1705809951). I'm sorry I have to ask this in parts, but I don't know how to express what I want well in English :(

Comment: Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Why is your question about getting the difference if what you really want to know is how to parse a date?

Comment: @Barmar Because I realize that I put it wrong. How could I convert a date to UNIX? EX: January 23, 2024, 01:18:49 am to UNIX -> (I don't know the equivalence, but it would be in this format (1705809951))

Comment: Are your dates `DD-MMM-YYYY` or `YYYY-MMM-DD`? You have the first in the question, but the second in a comment.

Comment: Now you say `January 23, 2024`. You've mentioned 3 different date formats in this question. What is your actual date format? There's no built-in method that will parse all these different date styles.

Comment: @Barmar, Thnx u!! I had bad format... With $interval->days It shows me the actual days that have passed, it doesn't matter if the months have 30, 31, or 500 days, correct?

Comment: The difference between March 1 and April 1 is 31 days. The difference between April 1 and May 1 is 30 days. But in both cases it's 1 month.

Comment: And the difference in days between Feb 1 and Mar 1 depends on whether it's a leap year, but it's still 1 month.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what the funcion you seek is "strtotime()"

The link for the doc is this one: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

This code may be of use to you:

```
echo strtotime('1970-10-01');
```

Best regards to u.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment, their date format is `1970-Oct-01`. `strtotime()` doesn't understand this format.

Comment: Hence the documentation link is there so that a solution or equation may be thought.

Comment: adequation not equation, I misspelled